# Store complex APIs objects and allow access from components and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I tried searching for "good practices" about how to link complex APIs that needs configuration or be provided by some manager and I can't seem to find how to make a "good" flow of data through redux.

So far I have been thinking of creating a reducer with actions that map each method I can call on a given complex object.

To put more context to it, I am building a framework to interact with a bluetooth device using this library (https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) and the startScanDevice returns me complex objects I can interact with (https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/#device) which also holds it's own state (a device knows if it's connected or not for instance, it also knows it's bluetooth services, etc.).

From what I have read, redux state should be having simple objects so it can have time travel properties and ease persistence.

What would be a good design to **to store those complex objects** and enable interaction between my components, reducers, actions, the store and this API I'm currently working on ?

Currently, I was thinking of giving callbacks to my API that would dispatch redux actions with new data to add in the redux store but I just can't seem to find a proper way to store my complex objects and provide access to it in order to invoke those methods and give them callbacks.

Here's a complete flow example :

- Invoking startScanDevice from the plx-ble API and provide a callback to receive device object given by that existing API
- **receive device objects and store it somewhere**
- Update redux store with proper information about the device object I need throughout the app
- **From a reducer, retrieve the device object from step 2 and invoke a method to interact with the device (example read from a characteristic)**
- Update redux store with read data from step 4

Steps 2 and 4 are the ones I can't seem to find a proper way to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

[Redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware could be helpful to you.

> Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return
>   a function instead of an action. The thunk can be used to delay the
>   dispatch of an action, or to dispatch only if a certain condition is
>   met. The inner function receives the store methods dispatch and
>   getState as parameters.

**to store those complex objects**

Don't complicate this.Try to keep your state as flat as possible.
Like

```
state={
  PoweredOn: false,
  Device: "deviceName",
  //similarly all
}
```

The more you keep it flat the more it will be easy to modify.

Comment: That will help to pass promises regarding method calls, but my major concern is that ble-plx does give me back complex objects with methods I need to invoke to interact with the bluetooth device. Those objects are the ones I can't seem to find a proper place to "store" (read hold the reference) and link with the rest...

Comment: Okay, now I understand the depth of problem. You are in response getting the methods also. But just to help me can you give me some simple object and how you want to invoke it later.

Answer (score 0):

The API doc you linked seems to have duplicate ways of calling these methods for exactly this reason.

For instance, you could connect to the device by calling `device.connect(options)` or by calling the package method `connectToDevice(deviceId, options)`.  The benefit of the second method being that you only need to track the ID value, and have no need to store the entire device object.

Comment: invoking connectToDevice returns a Promise for the complete device object that has methods to interact with the bluetooth device. From what you are saying, I'd have to ignore the returned device "object" and always fallback to the "primitive" manager methods call ?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Taking a quick glance, it looks like they have both versions of every function, so that should be pretty easy.  The response from the promise should still be used, mind you, as confirmation of success/failure (which you should subsequently dispatch to the relevant reducers).